# UITableViewCell accessoryType position change with cell height

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios4

I've made a UITableView with cells which have different height.
On each cell, I've attached an accessoryView (UIImageView).

Depending on the height of the cell, the accessoryType position is different (see attached image).
How can I correct it ?

It seems to be normal in any table view. No answers found.

Thanks for your help.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKOn0.png

UPDATE : My cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSDictionary *currentTime = [listOfTimes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


UITableViewCell *cell;
if([[currentTime objectForKey:@"freq"] intValue] > 0) cell = [self getCellFreqContentView:@"CellFreq"];
else cell = [self getCellContentView:@"Cell"];

[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];  
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];    
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

UILabel *lblTemp1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *lblTemp2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

if([[currentTime objectForKey:@"freq"] intValue] > 0) {

    lblTemp1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:[[currentTime objectForKey:@"arrival_time_seconds"] doubleValue]]],[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:[[currentTime objectForKey:@"departure_time_seconds"] doubleValue]]]];

    UILabel *lblTemp3 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    UILabel *lblTemp4 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];        
    lblTemp3.text = @"↓";
    lblTemp4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"A pass every %i minutes", nil), [[currentTime objectForKey:@"freq"] intValue]/60];
} else { 
    lblTemp1.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:[[currentTime objectForKey:@"departure_time_seconds"] doubleValue]]];
}

lblTemp2.text = [currentTime objectForKey:@"trip_headsign"];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

UIView *vv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
if(indexPath.row == [ScheduleManager getRowForTime:listOfTimes] && isCurrentPeriod == TRUE) {
    vv.backgroundColor = [BKColor colorWithHexString:@"54B8BB"];
}

// SPECIAL CASES
if([[currentTime valueForKey:@"runoff"] count] > 0 && useExceptions == TRUE) {
    // ACCESSORY
    cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"times-special.png"]];
}

cell.backgroundView = vv;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: How do you want this image to look like ?

Comment: The accessory is normally centered vertically in the cell and must be all right aligned on the same X-axis value.

Comment: Provide your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` please.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the accessoryView is positioned so that the distance from the right, top, and bottom edges is correlated in some way, so you have to reposition it.

Probably the best way is to subclass UITableViewCell, and override the layoutSubviews method:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect accessoryFrame = self.accessoryView.frame;
    accessoryFrame.origin.x = <desired position here>;
    self.accessoryView.frame = accessoryFrame;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I also have the same problem but it says Expression is not assignable.CAn you please help?

Comment: You can't directly apply a value to x and y in this context, instead do something like this:self.accessoryView.frame = CGRectMake(self.accessoryView.frame.origin.x, 10.0, self.accessoryView.frame.size.width, self.accessoryView.frame.size.height);

Comment: i have add this method but i m not able to change the position of it

Comment: Does not work. The frame of accessory view always remain zero irrespective of updations.                                                                                                  override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        var frame = accessoryView?.frame
        frame?.origin.x = 400
        accessoryView?.frame = frame!
    }